# playing a .wav file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, wav

I'm using visual studio 2010 express and I'm trying to write a simple program that will repeat a wave file 5 times(I'm running a windows xp sp3).

This is as far as I got:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;   
int main ()
{
    int a = 5;
        while(a >= 1){
            cout << "It's a wav file";
            PlaySound(L"SomeAudioFile-01.wav", NULL, SND_FILENAME);
            --a;
        }
    return 0;
 }
```

The problem is I keep getting this error message when I'm building it:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: It's a F**king Country, Configuration: Release Win32 --    ----
1>  mycode.cpp
1>..\..\..\..\..\Shaul's documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyProject\Release\SomeAudioFile-01.wav : fatal error LNK1136: invalid or corrupt file
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The file is perfectly fine and plays with no problems whatsoever outside visual studio.

Help would be truly appreciated.

Comment: According to MSDN, you should be using `PlaySound(TEXT("filePath.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME);`.
You can read more in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Try to clean the solution and rebuilding it.

Comment: I'm surprised `It's a F**king         Country` is a valid filename on Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of adding the `WAV` file to the project files, add it to the resources and use `SND_RESOURCE` instead of `SND_FILENAME`.

Answer (score 4):

You include the sound file as a object file, so the compiler tries to link with it. But it's a binary file that's not linkable (which is what the error message says).

Don't include the sound file in the project, so the environment won't link with it.

<sup>P.S. In the future, please refrain from using "bad" words on a public site like this.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the linker error, you need to tell the IDE to link with the **winmm.lib** library also, so open *Project/Properties/Configuration Properties/Linker/Input* and append **winmm.lib** in the *Additional Dependencies* field.

Also, use the following function profile:

PlaySound(L"audio.wav", NULL, SND_APPLICATION);