# CodeBlocks 13.12 adding sound

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Hello I just started learning c++, and my teacher wants us to create a game for our final exam.

I am using CodeBlocks 13.12 and can't seem to be able to add any game sound. I just need to play a simple .wav file if you guys could show me how that would look I'd greatly appreciate it.

The teacher made adding sound extra credit because he didn't actually show us how to do that. I have no clue as to how to do it so please show if I have to change anything in the settings.

Comment: You'll get an answer quicker if you post more info on what you have tried already.

Comment: Playing sound in your game has nothing to do with your IDE...

Comment: You'll probably want to specify what platform this is for. I don't believe C++ has anything built-in for playing sounds, so you'll end up needing a system-specific API.

Comment: http://www.portaudio.com/

Comment: @interrobang _I have no clue as to how to do it_ strongly implies op has not actually tried anything on account of not knowing what to do or how to go about it.

Comment: @computerfreaker - isn't playsound() a c++ routine? Or is that an external addin?

Comment: @JohnP I could be wrong, but the only PlaySound I'm aware of is [this Windows API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @computerfreaker - Ah, yeah, I think that's what I was thinking of. Thanks!

Comment: If you "just started" learning C++ you probably shouldn't be looking at sound yet. If your teacher wants you to anyway then I guess that can't be helped, but you'll have to tell us what platform (OSX,Linux,Windows, something else?) you're on, as well as what your current code looks like (not all of it - just generally how's your game structured. Do you use an external library like SDL? Or is it a console app? That kinda thing).

Comment: @computerfreaker *can't seem to be able to add any game sound* strongly implies that he has actually tried something.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked much with audio files either, but a quick search turned up the following links:

[StackOverflow: Playing a wav file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15384276/1704355)

[CodeProject: Audio files in c++](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/345648/how-can-we-play-audio-files-in-cplusplus-what-shou)

It looks that (for Windows at least) you can use

```
PlaySound
```

Check out the [Windows documentation for PlaySound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and make sure to include windows.h!

```
#include <windows.h>
```

Note: I should expand on AdamS's comment. CodeBlocks is your Integrated Development Environment (IDE). Your question is specific to the language C++ but not to the IDE CodeBlocks. If your code is correct but you still can't hear the sounds, then it could be an issue with your IDE or your computer.